# Animated Image with Applescript

Tags: applescript-objc

when I run a display alert, or a system alert is displayed I get
realize there is a little animation, from the window displayed, is there any way to do this with an image
(ImageView) programmatically without using a gif image?

Comment: What sort of animation are you wanting to do?

Comment: An image starts with a small size and increases.
Similar to a zoom.

Comment: @red_menace, would this be possible?

Comment: For a plain NSImageView, the only way to animate is with a GIF.  You should be able to do something like putting the image view in a scroll view, but I haven't done it to have a sample.

Comment: @red_menace, core animation is possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use Core Animation on an NSImageView.

Comment: @red_menace, I never used core animation, can you help me with this?

Comment: You could start with the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514).  You might get better answers if you could explain in your topics _exactly_ what it is you are wanting to do, and by "exactly", I mean "in excruciating detail" (including what you have tried and example code), to avoid excessive back and forth in the comments.